# ESP32-S3 USB circuit not recongnize by Windows

Tags: usb, esp32

I am designing an ESP32-S3 board and using the native USB feature through GPIO19 and GPIO20 on the ESP32-S3-WROOM-U1 module.

When I connect the USB to my Windows 11 computer, it is reported as unrecognized and no COM port is available for programming. My USB circuit includes a micro USB port connected to an ESD circuit, which is then connected to the ESP32-S3 USB circuit

When I check the Window's device manager it show up as this:

[image: Device manager]

Here is my USB circuit:
[image]
[image: USB circuit]

[ESP32 module datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-s3-wroom-1_wroom-1u_datasheet_en.pdf)

Things that I have tried:

1. Put the device in download mode
2. Make sure that my cables are data cables
3. Program using UART0 works just fine, I have a buzzer on board that I programmed for it to make sounds to confirm that nothing is wrong with other parts of the circuit.

Comment: Is it a [self-powered device](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32s3/api-reference/peripherals/usb_device.html#self-powered-device), and if so did you follow the guidance for that? Have you set the device up for [USB OTG console](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32s3/api-guides/usb-otg-console.html) to enable programming?

Comment: Hi @Polynomial,  The 5V from USB go through a LDO which step down to 3.3V to supply the ESP32. I don't think it is a power issue. And have check with a multimeter across Vcc and GND of ESP32 module it is exactly 3.3V.
When I programmed the ESP32 using a external USB to serial bridge via UART0 with arduinoIDE I have set the CDC and DFU to be enable on boot.

Comment: I didn't ask about self-powering because I suspected a power issue; VBUS monitoring is required for the USB interface to work correctly, and you need to follow the guidance in the linked page if you're operating a self-powered device.

Comment: It is a bus powering device

Comment: Page 25 of the schematic shows resistors on the USB datalines for impedance matching, do you have these resistors?

Comment: You don't show the connections to the module. Are you using pins that are named GPIO19 and GPIO20, or pins numbered 19 and 20, or something else? Which way the N and P are connected?

Comment: The most likely cause is that the USB pins are not correctly connected (swapped pins, solder bridge etc.) or that the module is not configured to enable USB-to-serial on on GPIO19/20 (through strapping pins and e-fuses). Both aspects are difficult to judge with the given information. Can you provide more details?

Comment: @Codo dont think its either of this; windows would not detect it at all if it wasn't at least transmitting some data on USB. Module configuration is irrelevant when the device is started in download-mode (and no fuses have been burnt). From personal experience with esp32: try different USB ports on your PC, with no hub in-between. Make sure your PCB isnt pulling any of the strapping-pins during boot, and make sure you have implemented a proper reset-circuit (see espressif H/W design guide).

Comment: @markus-nm I don't agree with the first point: if D+ and D- are swapped, shorted or only one of them is connected, Windows will detect that a device has been plugged in (due to the voltage on D+/D-) but the signals make no sense. Only if both D+ and D- are high impedance, then the device will be invisible. With the second point I can agree if the device was put into download mode correctly and no efuses have been burnt. But do we know for certain?

Comment: Well, knowing if a fuse was burned or not is something between OP and his memory to figure out. The devices leave the factory without any security or logging fuses burnt. Like I've said before; from experience this could be a transient issue best fixed by testing multiple USB ports, choosing shorter/better isolated USB cable, etc. 
One could test if the device is still working correctly and no critical fuses were burnt: connect it via it's UART interface using a bridge device (i.e. FT232X) and open the com-port with putty. It should print "download mode" every time it resets.

Comment: @Justme I connected the D- to gpio 19 and D+ to gpio20 . Not pin 19 and 20.

Comment: @Codo , all strapping pin are left unconnected (floating) . I have tried to connected directly to my PC motherboard without luck. I use a multimeter to check D+ and D- when esp32 is power on it is shorted to ground. But D+ and D- are not shorted to gnd when leave unconnected to the USB

Comment: @markus-nm I have tested with Arduino ide using USB to serial bridge. Esp32 is function as normal. Is it a way to check the fuse via Arduino ide?

Comment: @Ferrybig, I don't have these resistor connected

Comment: @markus-nm, Thank you so much, from your comment it give me the hint to go and fix my problem. Turn out my PCBA put the ESD chip in the wrong orientation cause both D+ and D- shorted to GND so there is no USB communication. I went and remove the ESD IC and manual solder to bridge the pins across the ESD IC and now it work like a charm.